# Unique values across two columns - at database or application level?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make my table only allow unique values across two columns - a compound key.

Would it be more efficient to do this at database level, or should I not create a compound key and let my application check if a record exists for the two unique values about to be submitted, and if so, do not create the row?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for compound key . See this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57548/how-to-set-up-multiple-fields-as-primary-key-in-mysql)

Comment: Checks on the data belong to the database not an application or user accessing the database. A database isn't an appendix of an application but can be shared by multiple by a lot of different applications or users. So to prevent having to reimplement checks over and over again, or worse, forgetting some these belong to *the* central place holding the data.

Comment: Check this on the database level - this is compulsory. And you may check on the client level additionally - if you want...

Answer (score 0):

Compound UNIQUE or PRIMARY keys pose little or no extra burden on database servers beyond what the keys' data types pose. (Data types like long strings with case-insensitive collation make for relatively expensive unique keys, for example. BIGINTs are cheap.)

And, if you use compound unique keys, your dbms will serve as a backstop to your application code. If there's a duplicate, you probably don't want to say "Exception: 1062 Duplicate" to your users. You'd be better off saying "that combination is already taken."

In the DBMS, go for it.  You need support for this feature set both in your table's unique key *and* your app to get this right.